# ¿Como funciona la funcion "is_callable?

Tags: php

No entiendo del todo como funciona "is_callable" en la siguiente estructura:

```
is_callable(array($controller, $metodo))
```

Sé que tiene algo que ver con que desde una variable se pueda llamar a una función pero la documentación no me lo deja nada claro. Además la inclusion de un array lo empeora. ¿se pueden meter mas variables que dos en el array?

Comment: que tienes contenido en `$controller` y en `$metodo`?

Comment: Tengo esto:
$controller = $peticion->getControlador() . 'Controller';
$metodo = $peticion->getMetodo();
Pero lo que me interesa es el funcionamiento de "is_callable" en una estructura como esa. Imagina tus propias variables que contentan lo que tu quieras. Lo necesito para saber su funcionamiento y cuando daría como resultado true o false. Insisto, necesito saber como funciona "is_calable" con array (como lo que mostré).

Comment: El array es únicamente para diferenciar una función de una clase (método) de una función global.

Answer (score 3):

`is_callable` devuelve true si el argumento/s es/son invocable(s)/llamable(s), o false en caso contrario.

Si `$controller` es una instancia de un objeto y `$metodo` un método público de dicha clase.

Por ejemplo:

```
class UserController {
   public function index()
   {
   ...
   }
}

$controller = new UserController();
$metodo = 'index';
```

`is_callable(array($controller, $metodo))` devuelve **true** porque es posible hacer la llamada (existe el método index en la clase):
`$controller->$metodo();`

Si no existiera, la llamada `$controller->$metodo()` daría error. De esta manera `is_callable` te protege antes de hacer la invocación real.

`is_callable` toma un único argumento, que será interpretado como un/a procedimiento/funcion global. Si se pasa un array, el 1er elemento es interpretado como una instancia a una clase y el segundo un método de dicha clase.

PD: Siento que la repuesta llegue tarde. Espero que le sirva a otros ;-)